# How to pass string argument to macro

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to print `IT SUCCESS\nET SUCCESS\n` using following code but it's failing in compilation with error `error: ‘printds’ was not declared in this scope` which I know is because it's taking macro input as `ds` literal. Does anyone know how to do this? The use case is that there are several printXX() functions which should be called based on value passed in macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOO(val) { \
    print ## val();    \
}
void printIT() { printf("IT SUCCESS\n"); }
void printET() { printf("ET SUCCESS\n"); }

int main() {
    const char* ds = "IT", es = "ET";
    FOO(ds); FOO(es);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a string literal to generate statements.  Maybe if you describe the _reason_ for needing this instead of your attempt at doing it, then someone can suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: ... In other words, what *exactly* is the "this" you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: added more details, I've several methods `queryServers`, `queryNodes`, `queryTargets` which I want to call using above trick. I know of alternatives of using switch case, if else ladder but just want to know if that can be done using macros. Thanks !

Comment: Your question is tagged as C++ and C. In C++, this is trivial to solve using an overloaded function. In C11, you could use [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic). So which language are you using?

Comment: Both C++ overload resolution and C generic selection provide for choosing among alternatives based on an expression's *type*, @IndianaKernick, not its *value*.  Inasmuch as the OP appears to be after the latter, neither of those options seems  applicable.

Comment: @IndianaKernick I am using C++17.

Comment: That's highly relevant information.  [c] tag removed.

Comment: Why do you want to use strings to choose a function? Perhaps it would be better to use an enum? Or maybe a function pointer? A virtual function? What thought process lead you to believe that you need to choose a function at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can change

```
 FOO(ds); FOO(es);
```

to

```
 FOO(IT); FOO(ET);
```

Because macro substitutions happen before your code is compiled.

But you can define a function called FOO like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printIT() { printf("IT SUCCESS\n"); }
void printET() { printf("ET SUCCESS\n"); }

void FOO(const string str)
{
    if(str=="IT")
        printIT();
    else
        printET();
}

int main()
{
    const char* ds = "IT",*es="ET";
    FOO(ds);FOO(es);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is trick to pass in `const char*` which is known at compile time too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> it's taking macro input as `ds` literal.

Yes, that's to be expected.  Preprocessor macros are expanded at compile time.  The arguments to function-like macros are the literal source-code tokens that appear between the parentheses in the macro invocation.  These have no additional meaning to the preprocessor.

> Does anyone know how to do this? The use case is that there are several printXX() functions which should be called based on value passed in macro.

Again, macros are expanded, to source code (approximately), at compile time.  The process does not and cannot take into account C++ runtime semantics such as converting variables' identifiers into corresponding values.

If runtime dynamic function dispatch based on variables' values is what you're after then you need an altogether different mechanism.  You could use ordinary conditional statements to select between different function calls, for example.  If you wanted to be even more dynamic then you could consider preparing a lookup table of function pointers, and using that to select and call appropriate functions.

In comments, you added

> I've several methods `queryServers`, `queryNodes`, `queryTargets` which I want to call using above trick.

You may be able to accomplish something similar to what you ask via templates or overloaded functions.  These mechanisms, too, operate at compile time, so they have no access to runtime information such as variables' values, but they do know about and rely upon C++ data types.

Alternatively, perhaps you're looking for [the Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: unfortunately I down voted(without knowing) the post but now it is locked and it says you can't change unless it edited so , can you please edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is that the Macros are preprocessor directives which are a fragment of code with a given name. if you use macro name in your program it will replace that code fragment into that place you use the macro name at compile time first stage called Pre-processing stage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOO(val) { \
    print ## val();    \
}
void printIT() { printf("IT SUCCESS\n"); }
void printET() { printf("ET SUCCESS\n"); }

int main() {
    const char* ds = "IT", es = "ET";
    FOO(ds); FOO(es);
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, you try to input ds and es variables into FOO function like macro. But ds and es variables declared in program stack only when you run the program. At the compile-time, it just treats them as only texts. Therefore macro function input it takes as text ds and es and replaced with val. That's why you got the compile time error. The following code fragment I have changed is working as you expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOO(val) { \
    print ## val();    \
}
void printIT() { printf("IT SUCCESS\n"); }
void printET() { printf("ET SUCCESS\n"); }

int main() {
    const char* ds = "IT", *es = "ET";
    FOO(IT); FOO(ET);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are interested you can find more about Macros in the following resources. 
[GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) and [Article about Macros](https://pmihaylov.com/macros-in-c/) . Also, you can view the preprocessed code using `g++ -E (your cpp file name)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution without MACRO:

```
void printIT() { printf("IT SUCCESS\n"); }
void printET() { printf("ET SUCCESS\n"); }

void foo(std::string_view s)
{
    static const std::map<std::string_view, void(*)()> funcs{
        {"IT", &printIT},
        {"ET", &printET}
    };

    auto it = funcs.find(s);
    if (it != funcs.end()) {
        (*it->second)();
    }
}

int main() {
    const char* ds = "IT";
    const char* es = "ET";
    foo(ds); foo(es);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5639d0ee5a467bca)